# Cant put list item on the left of container

Tags: html, position, html-lists

I can't figure out why my li items are stuck on the right side of the div container. I just want the li items to stick to the left side of the container.

**html**

```
<div id="side">
    <div class="sidemenu">
        <ul>
            <li>XC Camp</li>
            <li>Become a Sponsor</li>
            <li>Run Furman Community</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#side {
    background-color:#333333;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    border:2px solid white;
}

.sidemenu li {
    display:block;
    border-left:4px solid #8068a0;
    padding:6px;
    margin:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color:#8068a0;
}
```

Comment: Be mindful of the fact that these objects are in a <ul>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are as far left as they can go, because each `<li>` is contained within a `<ul>`. Unordered lists contain a default padding, so you'll want to add:

```
.sidemenu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
```

to your css.

Here's your example on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5aFV8/

Answer (score 1):

By default, `<ul>` (*Unordered List*) have `padding`, just have them set to `0`.

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Here is your updated code : http://jsfiddle.net/wVHSW/